# OOP C++: Which pattern: 2 classes with the partly same methods

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, factory

**Problem description:**

I need to implement 2 classes like following:

```
class A1 {
 common_method1();
 common_method2();
 foo1();
};

class A2 {
 common_method1();
 common_method2();
 foo2();
};
```

foo1() and foo2() has different logic.
foo1() and foo2() **may** have different args and return values.
common methods are the same OR have similar logic.

**Target:**
To implement factory that is able to generate A1 or A2 objects.
After call to factory::create() use foo1() or foo2() method respectively to the type of the object generated.

**Question**
How better to implement such logic in C++ C++/CLI?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is definitely a standard inheritance pattern. Create a base class `Parent`, which implements `common_method1` and `common_method2`. Create classes `A1` and `A2` which inherit from `Parent`.

If you need to do some special casing in one of the `common_method1` or `common_method2` methods in either `A1` or `A2`, make the methods `virtual` in `Parent`.

Implement `foo1` and `foo2` in respectively `A1` and `A2`.

EDIT: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a factory that returns a `Parent` type reference (abstract class). If you want to always `foo1` on `A1` objects, and `foo2` on `A2` objects, simply create a virtual method `bar` in the `Parent` interface, which, overriden in `A1`, will simply call `foo1`, and, overriden in `A2`, will simply call `foo2`.

Comment: Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu competent enough? By inheriting to reuse base class' code, you're missing the point of inheriting.

Comment: Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu are C++ bosses. :) n0rd, please, provide an explanation. Your POV is very interesting.

Comment: In object-oriented programming (OOP), inheritance is a way to compartmentalize and reuse code by creating collections of attributes and behaviors called objects that can be based on previously created objects.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming). I don't know Herb and Andrei, however, I do see implementation reuse as the main point of why you should use inheritance at all. If you don't reuse implementation, you might as well use only interfaces to implement from.

Comment: @DaddyM: Glad you solved your problem. We can do the "religious" "Inheritance is not meant for code reuse" debate elsewhere... ;)

Comment: Inheritance should be used to express "is a" relation. Using it for anything else is wrong. In order to reuse implementation composition is more than enough (but possibly it will require slightly more typing). Read this book: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm

Comment: I partly agree with you, however, it's easy to get LIPP (Lost In Programming Patterns). And to express a Is-a relationship, without inheriting any behaviour, an interface is more than sufficient. You are actually arguing that class inheritance is good-for-nothing. I too think many people misuse inheritance, however, I think this is a school example of when to actually use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a base class that implements the common functionality. Then use inheritance to create your final classes.

Your factory could return a pointer to the base class, which could include methods to determine the type. Or you could type cast it if needed.

Comment: dynamic_cast<A2 *>(base) will be NULL if the type is not A2. This would be the simplest and less error prone approach to determine the derived type.

Comment: What's the point for extracting base class and creating a factory, returning pointers to objects of that class if the next thing you are doing is determining object's concrete class and casting base class pointer to concrete class pointer?

Comment: 2 reece: dynamic_cast usage is the effect of bad design (Steven Dewhurst). Lets' consider cases without dynamic_cast

Comment: 2 n0rd: I have to work with legacy code. This case is the effect of my employer desire.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much else about your example, I think you'll want to create a master class that contains the common methods and then inherit those to a couple of base classes. 
Then you can use polymorphism to call either foo1() or foo2().  This site on [polymorphism](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson09.aspx) may help you since it's using the classic circle/square draw() example.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a heirarchy as such:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A_Base {
    // You can put your other common method here
    virtual void common_method();
    virtual ~A_Base();
}

struct A1 : A_Base {
    void foo1();
};

struct A2 : A_Base {
    void foo2();
};

struct Factory {
    // I'm just using an int for the condition,
    // but you can use anything
    A_Base *CreateA(int i) {
        if( i == 1 ) return new A1;
        if( i == 2 ) return new A2;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Factory f;

    // Create an object
    A_Base *pb = f.CreateA(1);

    A1 *pa1;
    A2 *pa2;

    // Run a common method
    pb->common_method();

    // Check the runtime type
    // (not really necessary, but you might need it)
    if( pa1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(pb) ) {
        pa1->foo1(); // Run the unique method
    } else if ( pa2 = dynamic_cast<A2*>(pb) ) {
        pa2->foo2(); // Or run the other unique method
    }

    // Delete the pointer
    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Yeah I'm using RTTI here near the end; not really good practice but you might need to know how to do that base->derived conversion